# Zooming parameters of PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

I wish to retrieve certain parameters for use when I zoom in a pdf file in iOS. Is it possible for me to get the point at which I touch to initiate the zooming? Can I also retrieve the zoom scale ?
I need the values of these parameters for use.

Answer (score 0):

You are not being very clear but it seems you need the following.

Put this in the viewDidLoad method of the view:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];

[self addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
[pinchGesture release];
```

Then use the info when the method is called (add this somewhere in the view):

```
- (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    float scale = [pinch scale];
    CGPoint pinchlocation = [pinch locationInView:self];
}
```

You can obviously change the name of the pinch callback method

Comment: you read my query well. Thanks for the response. Let me try by executing it.